# json_encode returns null for field with bullets as character

Tags: php, sql-server, json, linux

I am having a nightmare JSON encoding a database result from MSSQL.  It encodes it all but any field with characters such as a bullet returns NULL

I have trawled SO looking at other similar questions and answers but none of them worked for me so i'm posting here instead

I have tested in on my local machine (Windows) and it works using PDO.  I have tested it on the future production server (Linux) and it doesn't. Both php versions are 5.4.9

There is no possibility of upgrading/changing anything of the production server.

Here is the problematic code

```
<?php
ini_set('mssql.charset', 'UTF-8');

$server = 'XXXXXXX';

// Connect to MSSQL
$link = mssql_connect($server, 'XXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXX');

if (!$link) {
    die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
}

mssql_select_db('XXXXXXX', $link);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE view.[column] = 'XXXXXXX'";

$query = mssql_query($sql);

$rows = array();

while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($query, MSSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

// Clean up
mssql_free_result($query);

$json = array();

foreach($rows as $row) {
    foreach($row as $key => $value) {
        $json[$key] = trim($value);
    }   
}

var_dump($rows);
exit;

echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: What if you remove the trim? Is that the one returning null? if so you'll need to implement a custom trim function.

Comment: It still outputs null for that field with bullets in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the output from the DB is not UTF-8 encoded. [According to the PHP docs](http://us.php.net/json_encode), all input to json_encode() must be UTF-8.

Example:

```
$test = array('foo' => 'äöü', 'bar' => 'äöü');
$test['foo'] = mb_convert_encoding($test['foo'], 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');
echo json_encode($test);
```

Result:

```
{"foo":null,"bar":"\u00e4\u00f6\u00fc"}
```

Solution: Convert your DB output to UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  It's outputting something but now i get \r?

How do I get the correct html code which i think is u2022?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. Maybe you are applying an incorrect source charset. And/or maybe there is no direct translation of the bullet character in that charset to the UTF-8 bullet. What method do you use to convert the characters? Are you sure that you're using the correct charset, and that the data in the DB are consistently coded in that charset?

Comment: This got me further than anything so accepted answer. Would still like to find out how to turn the ? into the proper character

Comment: Ok, let's give it a try. What charset do the documents in the DB have? Could you apply this `BinString2BitSequence` function (http://php.net/manual/de/function.decbin.php#61464) on a single, unconverted bullet character and post the output?

Comment: I looked at phpinfo and the mssql charset wasn't set.  I've gotten closer but it outputs Â•

Comment: I don't know much about MSSQL, but there should be a charset set on the DB/tables and on the connection. And, when writing to the DB, you should be sure that everything that goes into the DB ist in the same charset, too. I've seen too many applications that are doomed because they have been processing mixed/undefined charsets over the years, and now they are in conversion hell. ;) Anything about the `BinString2BitSequence` stuff (see above)?